# What is the difference between SPECIFIC_SCHEMA and ROUTINE_SCHEMA in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES?

Tags: sql, sql-server

`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES` contains these two columns:

```
SPECIFIC_SCHEMA: Specific name of the schema.
ROUTINE_SCHEMA: Name of the schema that contains this function.
```

[technet doc](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188757.aspx)

For the `SPECIFIC_` and `ROUTINE_` versions of `CATALOG` and `NAME` are defined to be equivalent (-Specific name of the catalog. This name is the same as `ROUTINE_CATALOG`.-), but this verbiage is omitted for SCHEMA-

What is the difference between `SPECIFIC_SCHEMA` and `ROUTINE_SCHEMA`?

[Edit: Apparently 3+ years later this is being flagged as a duplicate so I have to clarify. The suggested duplicate is about different fields, so no I do not beleive it is a duplicate.]

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I had tagged this with ansi-sql-92 because the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views should be SQL-92 ANSI standard conforming.

Comment: In the SQL Server 2000 verbiage it specifically says [they are the same](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933197(v=sql.80).aspx). `sp_helptext 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES'` shows that in SQL Server 2012 both columns are in fact calculated the same way (`SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id)`). The [postgres docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/infoschema-routines.html) don't throw much light on it either except mentioning that the specific vs routine columns are concerned with possible overloaded functions.

Comment: This question belnogs on [dba.se]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between ROUTINE\_NAME and SPECIFIC\_NAME?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807795/what-is-the-difference-between-routine-name-and-specific-name)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it is a bit like a backwards compatibility.

The `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` itself is just used for easier migrations of Server versions and simplification. I will provide the examples based on SQL Server.

You may want (or maybe need) to use the table `sys.objects`, which basically provides nearly all the same information which were delivered by `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES`. In fact you need to use it, if you really want to know the real schema name for a procedure - as Microsoft already state in their own [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188757.aspx). But if you need to build a product which just want some basic information like if a routine exists or something like that, you won't go and take `sys.objects` it may change from server version to server version. Which makes it harder to maintain. The `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` basically stays the same over many versions. Only small changes will be applied and the work beneath the view, will be changed by Microsoft. This means you have a stable code for many years and many different server versions.

This may be the fact, that there are two columns with the same definition and therefore same content. It's the same like `SPECIFIC_NAME` and `ROUTINE_NAME` or `SPECIFIC_CATALOG` and `ROUTINE_CATALOG`. They are basically the same, as Microsoft self stated in their docs.

It could be a relic, which may stay there for ever, just for the compatibility t other DBMS code or older versions of SQL Server itself.

Just by the way, Postgres have the same two rows which both contains the same content.

Comment: The current docs don't show this--that's specifically what OP says. But as @martin-smith's comments indicates the were stated to be the same in the 2000 version of the docs. In any case I think this is sufficiently answered now so am accepting.

Comment: No documentation says that. Even in Postgres not. Just in the comments there is a hint that both are the same. On SQL Server you can take a look at the code behind it and see that both are defined exactly the same. Documentation is nice to have, but just read the code and you know how it works. :-D

Answer (score 1):

This is for overloading. And the question is a duplicate of [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807795/what-is-the-difference-between-routine-name-and-specific-name).

Essentially, you can overload a function in just one schema in the SQL spec.

### Overloading and lookup.

Let's take for instance `ST_Union`, which you can see documented with signatures [here](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Union.html), and [here](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Union.html)

```
SELECT specific_catalog, specific_schema, specific_name, routine_catalog, routine_schema, routine_name
FROM information_schema.routines
WHERE routine_name = 'st_union';
 specific_catalog | specific_schema |  specific_name  | routine_catalog | routine_schema | routine_name 
------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+--------------
 test             | public          | st_union_259584 | test            | public         | st_union
 test             | public          | st_union_259621 | test            | public         | st_union
 test             | public          | st_union_259622 | test            | public         | st_union
 test             | public          | st_union_260448 | test            | public         | st_union
 test             | public          | st_union_260450 | test            | public         | st_union
 test             | public          | st_union_260452 | test            | public         | st_union
 test             | public          | st_union_260454 | test            | public         | st_union
 test             | public          | st_union_260456 | test            | public         | st_union
(8 rows)
```

You can see here that `st_union` is overloaded 8 different times. What you can't see is why: some of them are aggregates, some of them accept `rasters` and others `geometry`. Point is, you call `st_union` depending on what you call it with you may get `st_union_260454` or `st_union_259621`, or any of the others.

Catch is, SQL permits you to get a different one depending on the schema you call it in.

```
SELECT current_schema;
```

That returns `public`. That's the first schema in my `search_path`. I can create a sub that provides a 9th `ST_Union`, but one that only works inside the schema `foobar`. Doing so would provide the 9th overload of routine_name `st_union`. That would make the above return something like this...

```
SELECT specific_catalog, specific_schema, specific_name, routine_catalog, routine_schema, routine_name
FROM information_schema.routines
WHERE routine_name = 'st_union';
 specific_catalog | specific_schema |  specific_name  | routine_catalog | routine_schema | routine_name 
------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+--------------
 test             | public          | st_union_259584 | test            | public         | st_union
 test             | public          | st_union_259621 | test            | public         | st_union
 test             | public          | st_union_259622 | test            | public         | st_union
 test             | public          | st_union_260448 | test            | public         | st_union
 test             | public          | st_union_260450 | test            | public         | st_union
 test             | public          | st_union_260452 | test            | public         | st_union
 test             | public          | st_union_260454 | test            | public         | st_union
 test             | public          | st_union_270456 | test            | foobar         | st_union
(9 rows)
```

- If my `search_path` is just `foobar` then the signature better match the types of `st_union_270456`
- If my `search_path` is `foobar,public` then either `foobar` is overriding a routine in `public` or providing a routine `public` is not providing.

`CURRENT_SCHEMA` is just the first schema in `search_path` for PostgreSQL. PostgreSQL extends upon the spec by allowing you to resolve things in multiple schema.

Comment: Can you expan on that answer a little. I don't immediately follow what you mean by overloading in the case.