# What is the difference between ROUTINE_NAME and SPECIFIC_NAME?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES view, ROUTINE_NAME and SPECIFIC_NAME are present. As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188757.aspx) they are the same. Are they there just for backward compatibility of some sorts? If not why is redundant fields being included in the view?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ANSI SQL Standard does not prohibit overloading, i.e. two objects with the same name. The SPECIFIC_NAME is a unique name for an overloaded module, while the ROUTINE_NAME is not guaranteed to be unique. The same is true wherever you see SPECIFIC, such as SPECIFIC_CATALOG, and SPECIFIC_SCHEMA.

T-SQL does not have this capability, so SPECIFIC_NAME and ROUTINE_NAME are always the same.

The only SQL implementation that I know of that supports this feature is PostgreSQL (see here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/infoschema-routines.html), but it's possible that I'm mistaken. My Oracle is rusty.

I'm not totally sure how SPECIFIC_CATALOG would work, although I suppose it's possible it could include some path or server information, to distinguish between two different databases with the same name.